# row equivalent $(A|b)$ and $(A|c)$ and their solution space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, systems-of-equations

let  $(A|b)$ and $(A|c)$  be row equivalent matrices,

Where $A\in M_{m\times n} (\mathbb{F})$ and $b,c \in \mathbb{F}^{m}$

**The Questions:**

a) Show that $Ax=b$ has a solution iff $Ax=c$ has a solution.

b) Show that if $Ax=b$ has no solution so rank($c$)$=1$

c) Given that $Ax=b$ has no solution and that $(A|c)$ is in row canonical form. Find column vector $\vec{c}$.

**Shat I tried so far:**

**a)** If $(A|b)$ and $(A|c)$ are row equivalent matrices, it means that after a finite number of row operations, you can change one to the other and back.

After reducing $(A|b)$ to a canonical form we get:

$$ \left[
\begin{array}{cccc|c}
  1&0&\cdots&0&\tilde{b_{1}}\\
  0&1&\cdots&0&\tilde{b_{2}}\\
  \vdots& &\ddots&0&\vdots\\
  0&\cdots&\cdots&\ddots&\tilde{b_{m}}\\
\end{array}
\right] $$

Where $\tilde{b}$ is the new vector column $b$ the forms after applying the row operations on $A$.

The same for $(A|c)$:
$$ \left[
\begin{array}{cccc|c}
  1&0&\cdots&0&\tilde{c_{1}}\\
  0&1&\cdots&0&\tilde{c_{2}}\\
  \vdots& &\ddots&0&\vdots\\
  0&\cdots&\cdots&\ddots&\tilde{c_{m}}\\
\end{array}
\right] $$

Proof by contradiction. If $b \neq c$, so $\tilde{b} \neq \tilde{c}$ because the same row operations were applied.

The equation systems:

$$ \left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
  1&0&\cdots&0\\
  0&1&\cdots&0\\
  \vdots& &\ddots&0\\
  0&\cdots&\cdots&\ddots\\
\end{array}
\right] 
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
  x_{1}\\
  x_{2}\\
  \vdots\\
  x_{m}\\
\end{array}
\right] =
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
  \tilde{b_{1}}\\
  \tilde{b_{2}}\\
  \vdots\\
  \tilde{b_{m}}\\
\end{array}
\right],
 \left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
  1&0&\cdots&0\\
  0&1&\cdots&0\\
  \vdots& &\ddots&0\\
  0&\cdots&\cdots&\ddots\\
\end{array}
\right] 
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
  x_{1}\\
  x_{2}\\
  \vdots\\
  x_{m}\\
\end{array}
\right] =
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
  \tilde{c_{1}}\\
  \tilde{c_{2}}\\
  \vdots\\
  \tilde{c_{m}}\\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

Will have a $x_{i}=\tilde{b_{i}}$, $x_{i}=\tilde{c_{i}}$

But because $\tilde{b} \neq \tilde{c}$ it's a contridiction to the assumption that, therefore $Ax=b$ has a solution iff $Ax=c$

**b)** If $Ax=b$ has no solution, than after reducing $A$ to canonical form, exist $b_{i} \neq 0$ if forn of a row of $0$.

If rank($c$)$\neq 1$ so $c=0$ and from question (a) I proved that $c=b$, and for a homogeneous equations system there are always either infinite solutions or one solution.

Therefore for $Ax=b$ to have no solution, rank($b$) = rank($c$) = 1

**c)** I'm pretty stuck here, I know that for
$$c=(c_{1},c_{2},...,c_{n},c_{n+1},...,c_{m})$$
At least one element from $\{c_{n+1},...,c_{m}\}$ ha to be $c_{i} \neq 0$.

But I don't know how to show it.

I'm not sure if my assumptions in question (a) were right and that I used them correctly.